# Open a PDF at a specified page Platform independent in java

Tags: java, kotlin, awt, nio

I am currently searching for a way to open a (local) PDF in an external program at a specified page via java.
I tried it with the following code:

```
fun openPDF(url: String, at: Int) {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                val uri = URI("${Paths.get(url).toUri()}#page=$at")

                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri)
        }
}
```

it opens the pdf in the default program, but not at the specified page.

Has anybody a solution so that the pdf opens up at the page i wish for? (In the default program or in the default browser)